# How can I echo only last value from the results

Tags: php

How can I echo only the last value from the results.

I'm using the following code but it is displaying like the example below.

```
<?php
                        $total = 0;
                        foreach($products as $product){
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                            <?php
                            $total_item = $product['quantity'] * $product['sale_price'];
                            $total += $total_item;
                            
                            echo formatcurrency($total);
                            
                            ?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
```

This is what i'm getting but i want only the last value. $526.00

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgv73.png)

Comment: I just updated the code more simply. You can easily implement the function by replacing the echo state into outside of foreach loop. :)
Good Luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please output the total value outside of the foreach loop. it would be more simply.

```
<?php
$total = 0;
foreach($products as $product){
?>
<tr>
    <td>
    <?php
    $total_item = $product['quantity'] * $product['sale_price'];
    $total += $total_item;
    ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
}
echo formatcurrency($total);
?>
```

Best Regards

Comment: Thank you very much Lee, worked just as i needed. Really appreciate your help.